# Make a count funtion for a dictionary in python with keys in the form of coordinates (x,y)

Tags: python, python-3.x

I need to make a count function but this is a little bit harder than the usual. The dictionary has keys in the form of coordinates (x,y) and the value is either "player1" or "player2". I want to be able to count all the values with a specific x or y value. For example:

```
count("column", 500, player1)
```

should count number of values where they key x is 500 and the value of y doesn't matter so (500, anything).

I am pretty much clueless and any help is appreciated.

Comment: what is `"column"` and it should be treated?

Comment: "column" is for the value x and "row" is for value y. So if i write count("row", 500, "player1") the funtion should count the number of values where they key y is 500 adn the value of x doenst matter for the values "player1" in the dict

Answer (score 1):

Use the following function called `counter`:

```
def counter(d, item_type, key_value, val):
    key_map = {'column': 0, 'row': 1}

    if item_type not in key_map:
        return None

    return [k[key_map[item_type]] for k,v in d.items() if v == val].count(key_value)

d = {
    (100, 200): 'player2', 
    (500, 200): 'player2', 
    (500, 300): 'player1', 
    (500, 500): 'player1'}

print(counter(d, "row", 500, "player1"))     # 1
print(counter(d, "column", 500, "player1"))  # 2
print(counter(d, "row", 200, "player2"))     # 2
```

Comment: As i said to hte reply before i might have been a little to unclear.  The dict should look something like this dict = { (100,200): player1, (230,500):player2, (100, 234):player1} and if i for example take count("column", 100, "player1") i should get the result 2 because 2 of them has the x value 100.

Comment: @heheecksde, so, have you tried my solution? it works as expected, pay attention. It will return `2` for your input dict and `count("column", 100, "player1") `

Comment: yes i tested it and it worked. sorry that i replied before testing it. I hav enever written in this way before so it seemed a little odd. But thank you very much. it is very appreciated :) Dont know why i cant upvote your solution

Comment: @heheecksde, that's ok